# Ember.js: How do I include compiled templates correctly in index.html?

Tags: javascript, templates, ember.js

I am new to ember.js. I managed to pre-compile templates using a Grunt file. However, when I include them in an index.html, I see an empty page, templates are not rendered. What am I doing wrong? If I don't compile templates and include directly in index.html it works.

I installed everything using yeoman.io (using bower packages grunt-ember-templates, ember, webapp scaffolding)

My index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My New App</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>

  <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/handlebars/handlebars.js"></script>    
  <script src="bower_components/ember/ember.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/templates.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My App.js:

```
    App = Ember.Application.create();

    App.Router.map(function() {
      // put your routes here
    });

    App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
      model: function() {
        return ['red', 'yellow', 'blue'];
      }
    });
```

Templates:

Edit: application.hbs

```
    <h2>Welcome to Ember.js</h2>

    {{outlet}}
```

Edit: index.hbs

```
    <ul>
    {{#each item in model}}
      <li>{{item}}</li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
```

Compiled templates in templates.js:

```
define(["ember"], function(Ember){

Ember.TEMPLATES["application"] = Ember.Handlebars.template(function anonymous(Handlebars,depth0,helpers,partials,data) {
this.compilerInfo = [4,'>= 1.0.0'];
helpers = this.merge(helpers, Ember.Handlebars.helpers); data = data || {};
  var buffer = '', stack1;


  data.buffer.push("<h2>Welcome to Ember.js</h2>\n\n");
  stack1 = helpers._triageMustache.call(depth0, "outlet", {hash:{},hashTypes:{},hashContexts:{},contexts:[depth0],types:["ID"],data:data});
  if(stack1 || stack1 === 0) { data.buffer.push(stack1); }
  return buffer;

});

Ember.TEMPLATES["index"] = Ember.Handlebars.template(function anonymous(Handlebars,depth0,helpers,partials,data) {
this.compilerInfo = [4,'>= 1.0.0'];
helpers = this.merge(helpers, Ember.Handlebars.helpers); data = data || {};
  var buffer = '', stack1, self=this;

function program1(depth0,data) {

  var buffer = '', stack1;
  data.buffer.push("\n  <li>");
  stack1 = helpers._triageMustache.call(depth0, "item", {hash:{},hashTypes:{},hashContexts:{},contexts:[depth0],types:["ID"],data:data});
  if(stack1 || stack1 === 0) { data.buffer.push(stack1); }
  data.buffer.push("</li>\n ");
  return buffer;
  }

  data.buffer.push("\n<ul>\n    ");
  stack1 = helpers.each.call(depth0, "item", "in", "model", {hash:{},hashTypes:{},hashContexts:{},inverse:self.noop,fn:self.program(1, program1, data),contexts:[depth0,depth0,depth0],types:["ID","ID","ID"],data:data});
  if(stack1 || stack1 === 0) { data.buffer.push(stack1); }
  data.buffer.push("\n</ul>\n");
  return buffer;

});

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not specific about how you are compiling your templates. Are they from *.hbs files, or are you using a different approach ?

It seems to me, that you are attempting to compile your templates.html file as a single template, as it has this code in the template itself:

```
data.buffer.push("\n<script type=\"text/x-handlebars\">\n
```

Each of your template files should only contain the contents of the template, and not the script tag itself.

Normally, you will put each .hbs file in a separate file that together with the used to determine the name of the template.

I did a presentation earlier, where I am live coding an application using grunt. This screencast do show how you can organize your .hbs files, while the source code shows how they are complied. This shows how my development process is, and it goes through building a complete app with grunt as the build system.

The presentation is up on YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KH5RreHtaaQ
The source code is on GitHub: https://github.com/joachimhs/WarmCroc-Ember

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes they were all from one index.hbs file, and script tag was not omitted. I believe you mean file names are used as template names? So I removed the <script> tag from templates, I moved first one into an application.hbs, and second one (with id=index) to an index.hbs. I compiled, still no output.

Comment: I updated original description with above changes. I checked your example in github. My templates above look similar, so I don't see why it did not work. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by removing amd:true option from grunt-ember-templates grunt configuration. To be honest I had added it without knowing what it does.

For completeness, here is my current grunt file. This file is autogenerated by yeoman.io webapp generator, and I have only added a grunt-ember-templates configuration to it (ones defined under emberTemplates).

As of today, all guides I found online were incomplete or out of date, and this worked for me.

```
// Generated on 2014-03-24 using generator-webapp 0.4.8
'use strict';

// # Globbing
// for performance reasons we're only matching one level down:
// 'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
// use this if you want to recursively match all subfolders:
// 'test/spec/**/*.js'

module.exports = function (grunt) {

    // Load grunt tasks automatically
    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

    // Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
    require('time-grunt')(grunt);

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-ember-templates');
    // Define the configuration for all the tasks
    grunt.initConfig({

        // Project settings
        config: {
            // Configurable paths
            app: 'app',
            dist: 'dist'
        },

        emberTemplates: {
            compile: {
                options: {

                    templateBasePath: /app\/templates\//
                //templateName: function(sourceFile) {
                //        console.log(sourceFile.replace(/app\/templates\//, ''));
                //       return sourceFile.replace(/app\/templates\//, '');
                //    }
                },
                files: {
                    '<%= config.app %>/scripts/templates.js': ['<%= config.app %>/templates/*.hbs']
                }
            }
        },
        // Watches files for changes and runs tasks based on the changed files
        watch: {
            emberTemplates: {
                files: '<%= config.app %>/templates/*.hbs',
                tasks: ['emberTemplates', 'livereload']
            },
            bower: {
                files: ['bower.json'],
                tasks: ['bowerInstall']
            },
            js: {
                files: ['<%= config.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'],
                tasks: ['jshint'],
                options: {
                    livereload: true
                }
            },
            jstest: {
                files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js'],
                tasks: ['test:watch']
            },
            gruntfile: {
                files: ['Gruntfile.js']
            },
            styles: {
                files: ['<%= config.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
                tasks: ['newer:copy:styles', 'autoprefixer']
            },
            livereload: {
                options: {
                    livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
                },
                files: [
                    '<%= config.app %>/{,*/}*.html',
                    '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                    '<%= config.app %>/images/{,*/}*'
                ]
            }
        },

        // The actual grunt server settings
        connect: {
            options: {
                port: 9000,
                livereload: 35729,
                // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside
                hostname: 'localhost'
            },
            livereload: {
                options: {
                    open: true,
                    base: [
                        '.tmp',
                        '<%= config.app %>'
                    ]
                }
            },
            test: {
                options: {
                    port: 9001,
                    base: [
                        '.tmp',
                        'test',
                        '<%= config.app %>'
                    ]
                }
            },
            dist: {
                options: {
                    open: true,
                    base: '<%= config.dist %>',
                    livereload: false
                }
            }
        },

        // Empties folders to start fresh
        clean: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    dot: true,
                    src: [
                        '.tmp',
                        '<%= config.dist %>/*',
                        '!<%= config.dist %>/.git*'
                    ]
                }]
            },
            server: '.tmp'
        },

        // Make sure code styles are up to par and there are no obvious mistakes
        jshint: {
            options: {
                jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
                reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
            },
            all: [
                'Gruntfile.js',
                '<%= config.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                '!<%= config.app %>/scripts/vendor/*',
                'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
            ]
        },

        // Mocha testing framework configuration options
        mocha: {
            all: {
                options: {
                    run: true,
                    urls: ['http://<%= connect.test.options.hostname %>:<%= connect.test.options.port %>/index.html']
                }
            }
        },

        // Add vendor prefixed styles
        autoprefixer: {
            options: {
                browsers: ['last 1 version']
            },
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
                    src: '{,*/}*.css',
                    dest: '.tmp/styles/'
                }]
            }
        },

        // Automatically inject Bower components into the HTML file
        bowerInstall: {
            app: {
                src: ['<%= config.app %>/index.html'],
                ignorePath: '<%= config.app %>/'
            }
        },

        // Renames files for browser caching purposes
        rev: {
            dist: {
                files: {
                    src: [
                        '<%= config.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                        '<%= config.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                        '<%= config.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.*',
                        '<%= config.dist %>/styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*',
                        '<%= config.dist %>/*.{ico,png}'
                    ]
                }
            }
        },

        // Reads HTML for usemin blocks to enable smart builds that automatically
        // concat, minify and revision files. Creates configurations in memory so
        // additional tasks can operate on them
        useminPrepare: {
            options: {
                dest: '<%= config.dist %>'
            },
            html: '<%= config.app %>/index.html'
        },

        // Performs rewrites based on rev and the useminPrepare configuration
        usemin: {
            options: {
                assetsDirs: ['<%= config.dist %>', '<%= config.dist %>/images']
            },
            html: ['<%= config.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
            css: ['<%= config.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css']
        },

        // The following *-min tasks produce minified files in the dist folder
        imagemin: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= config.app %>/images',
                    src: '{,*/}*.{gif,jpeg,jpg,png}',
                    dest: '<%= config.dist %>/images'
                }]
            }
        },

        svgmin: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= config.app %>/images',
                    src: '{,*/}*.svg',
                    dest: '<%= config.dist %>/images'
                }]
            }
        },

        htmlmin: {
            dist: {
                options: {
                    collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
                    collapseWhitespace: true,
                    removeAttributeQuotes: true,
                    removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
                    removeEmptyAttributes: true,
                    removeOptionalTags: true,
                    removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                    useShortDoctype: true
                },
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= config.dist %>',
                    src: '{,*/}*.html',
                    dest: '<%= config.dist %>'
                }]
            }
        },

        // By default, your `index.html`'s <!-- Usemin block --> will take care of
        // minification. These next options are pre-configured if you do not wish
        // to use the Usemin blocks.
        // cssmin: {
        //     dist: {
        //         files: {
        //             '<%= config.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
        //                 '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
        //                 '<%= config.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'
        //             ]
        //         }
        //     }
        // },
        // uglify: {
        //     dist: {
        //         files: {
        //             '<%= config.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js': [
        //                 '<%= config.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js'
        //             ]
        //         }
        //     }
        // },
        // concat: {
        //     dist: {}
        // },

        // Copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
        copy: {
            dist: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    dot: true,
                    cwd: '<%= config.app %>',
                    dest: '<%= config.dist %>',
                    src: [
                        '*.{ico,png,txt}',
                        '.htaccess',
                        'images/{,*/}*.webp',
                        '{,*/}*.html',
                        'styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*'
                    ]
                }]
            },
            styles: {
                expand: true,
                dot: true,
                cwd: '<%= config.app %>/styles',
                dest: '.tmp/styles/',
                src: '{,*/}*.css'
            }
        },

        // Run some tasks in parallel to speed up build process
        concurrent: {
            server: [
                'copy:styles'
            ],
            test: [
                'copy:styles'
            ],
            dist: [
                'copy:styles',
                'imagemin',
                'svgmin'
            ]
        }
    });


    grunt.registerTask('serve', function (target) {
        if (target === 'dist') {
            return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
        }

        grunt.task.run([
            'clean:server',
            'concurrent:server',
            'autoprefixer',
            'connect:livereload',
            'watch'
        ]);
    });

    grunt.registerTask('server', function (target) {
        grunt.log.warn('The `server` task has been deprecated. Use `grunt serve` to start a server.');
        grunt.task.run([target ? ('serve:' + target) : 'serve']);
    });

    grunt.registerTask('test', function (target) {
        if (target !== 'watch') {
            grunt.task.run([
                'clean:server',
                'concurrent:test',
                'autoprefixer'
            ]);
        }

        grunt.task.run([
            'connect:test',
            'mocha'
        ]);
    });

    grunt.registerTask('build', [
        'clean:dist',
        'useminPrepare',
        'concurrent:dist',
        'autoprefixer',
        'concat',
        'cssmin',
        'uglify',
        'copy:dist',
        'rev',
        'usemin',
        'htmlmin'
    ]);

    grunt.registerTask('default', [
        'newer:jshint',
        'test',
        'build'
    ]);
};
```